# Android supported devices 0 devices

Tags: android, google-play

When I am uploading the release apk google play console is saying that it doesn't support any device. and when I published this for alpha testing it says that "your device isn't conpatible for this version".

Here is my ap gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cofoz.cofoz"
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        preDexLibraries true

        jumboMode true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), "proguard-rules.pro"
            //shrinkResources true
            //Other parameters
            //debuggable false
            //jniDebuggable false
            //renderscriptDebuggable false
            //signingConfig playStoreConfig //Add your own signing config
            //pseudoLocalesEnabled false
            //zipAlignEnabled true


            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // Disables PNG crunching for the release build type.
            crunchPngs false

        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.andremion:counterfab:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    // Required only if Facebook login support is required
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
    //implementation 'com.github.DanielMartinus:Stepper-Touch:0.6'
    //implementation 'com.stone.vega.library:VegaLayoutManager:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    //implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.8'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
    //implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.0'
    //implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.github.thomper:sweet-alert-dialog:v1.4.0'
    // Shimmer
    //implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
    //implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    //implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.4'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.3'
    //implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:4.13.1'
    //implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-beta2"

    implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1') {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.2.0@aar') { transitive = true }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have already defined minSdk and targetSdk.
Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.cofoz.cofoz">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" android:minSdkVersion="17" />


    <application
        android:name=".CardLoading"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
```

Comment: You don't need the following line `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />`. Remove it. You also don't need to following if you're using gradle : `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" android:minSdkVersion="17" />`

Comment: nothing worked man, It still  says "Supported Android devices : 0 devices"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing the

```
implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

dependency to

```
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```